# How do I show the content and attachments of a .OFT or .MSG file on the html page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, outlook, sharepoint-2013

I have `.OFT` and `.MSG` files, hosted on a SharePoint server. Some of them have attachments and images along with the content. 
I have links to those `.OFT` and `.MSG` files.

Now I want to read the content, attachments and images of those files and display them on an HTML page as an email.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you provide more details? Maybe an image could help to clarify your problem :)

Comment: Basically I am trying to create an archive of outlook emails on a webpage. 

I may use a screenshot of the email. This will display the background images and colours in the email. But selecting a text and opening links will not be possible.

I may use simple paragraphs, background images and font colours to build the structure of an email. But for every new email, I have to create the HTML structure, style it with CSS and link out the attachments.

I have links to the .oft and .msg files. Is there a way to read these outlook email files using JavaScript?

Let me know if I am not clear.

Comment: Where does your code run? Client side or server